# Stuck with VarLenQField example from Scapy's documentation

Tags: python, scapy

I am going through the Scapy example of [Adding new protocols](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_dissect.html) and I'm stuck. The aged code as presented on their page throws an error in Python 3 because of `string->bytes` conversion, but that's a minor thing. I have written my own implementations of their `vlenq2str()` and `str2vlenq()`. I call them `vlenq2m()` and `m2vlenq()` respectively. `vlenq2m` converts integer values to bytes (to be used in the packet's raw data), and `m2vlenq` converts these bytes from the packet's raw data back to integer (as scapy-internal representation).

My actual problem is that at some point after calling the packet's `show2` method, scapy throws a TypeError and I have no clue why.

Here is my minimal example (modernized version of the code from scapy's documentation):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


from scapy.fields import Field, StrLenField
from scapy.packet import Packet, ls
from scapy.compat import raw


def vlenq2m(val: int) -> bytes:
    s = list()
    s.append(val & 0x7F)
    val = val >> 7
    while val:
        s.append(0x80 | (val & 0x7F))
        val = val >> 7
    s.reverse()
    return bytes(s)


def m2vlenq(m: bytes=b"") -> tuple[bytes, int]:
    i = l = 0
    for n in m:
        l = l << 7
        l = l + (n & 0x7F)
        i = i + 1
        if not n & 0x80:
            break
    return m[i + 1:], l


class VarLenQField(Field):
    """variable length quantities"""
    __slots__ = ["fld"]
    def __init__(self, name, default, fld):
        Field.__init__(self, name, default)
        self.fld = fld
    def i2m(self, pkt, x):
        if x is None:
            f = pkt.get_field(self.fld)
            x = f.i2len(pkt, pkt.getfieldval(self.fld))
            x = vlenq2m(x)
        return raw(x)
    def m2i(self, pkt, x):
        if s is None:
            return None, 0
        return m2vlenq(x)[1]
    def addfield(self, pkt, s, val):
        return s + self.i2m(pkt, val)
    def getfield(self, pkt, s):
        return m2vlenq(s)


class Foo(Packet):
    name = "Foo"
    fields_desc = [
            VarLenQField("len", None, "data"),
            StrLenField("data", "", "len"),
            ]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    f = Foo(data="test data")
    breakpoint()
    f.show2()
```

Here is the error stack:

```
$ python -i sominimal.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\mlp-monitor\src\mlptc\sominimal.py", line 64, in <module>
    f.show2()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\mmon\lib\site-packages\scapy\packet.py", line 1289, in show2
    return self.__class__(raw(self)).show(dump, indent, lvl, label_lvl)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\mmon\lib\site-packages\scapy\base_classes.py", line 266, in __call__
    i.__init__(*args, **kargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\mmon\lib\site-packages\scapy\packet.py", line 158, in __init__
    self.dissect(_pkt)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\mmon\lib\site-packages\scapy\packet.py", line 875, in dissect
    s = self.do_dissect(s)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\mmon\lib\site-packages\scapy\packet.py", line 839, in do_dissect
    s, fval = f.getfield(self, s)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\mmon\lib\site-packages\scapy\fields.py", line 1380, in getfield
    len_pkt = self.length_from(pkt)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Here is my careful stepping through the debugger up to the point where the error occurs.

```
$ python -i sominimal.py
> d:\python\mlp-monitor\src\mlptc\sominimal.py(65)<module>()
-> f.show2()
(Pdb) s
--Call--
> c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\mmon\lib\site-packages\scapy\packet.py(1277)show2()
-> def show2(self, dump=False, indent=3, lvl="", label_lvl=""):
(Pdb) n
> c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\mmon\lib\site-packages\scapy\packet.py(1289)show2()
-> return self.__class__(raw(self)).show(dump, indent, lvl, label_lvl)
(Pdb) s
--Call--
> c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\mmon\lib\site-packages\scapy\compat.py(50)raw()
-> def raw(x):
(Pdb) n
> c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\mmon\lib\site-packages\scapy\compat.py(53)raw()
-> return bytes(x)
(Pdb) n
--Return--
> c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\mmon\lib\site-packages\scapy\compat.py(53)raw()->b'\ttest data'
-> return bytes(x)
(Pdb) n
--Call--
> c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\mmon\lib\site-packages\scapy\base_classes.py(256)__call__()
-> def __call__(cls, *args, **kargs):
(Pdb) n
> c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\mmon\lib\site-packages\scapy\base_classes.py(257)__call__()
-> if "dispatch_hook" in cls.__dict__:
(Pdb) n
> c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\mmon\lib\site-packages\scapy\base_classes.py(265)__call__()
-> i = cls.__new__(cls, cls.__name__, cls.__bases__, cls.__dict__)
(Pdb) s
> c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\mmon\lib\site-packages\scapy\base_classes.py(266)__call__()
-> i.__init__(*args, **kargs)
(Pdb) type(i)
<class '__main__.Foo'>
(Pdb) type(i.__init__)
<class 'method'>
(Pdb) n
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
> c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\mmon\lib\site-packages\scapy\base_classes.py(266)__call__()
-> i.__init__(*args, **kargs)
```

Comment: It would have helped a lot to know what scapy version you're using

Comment: @Cukic0d: sorry, I forgot to mention it. I used scapy 2.4.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're super close. You only missed a small, weird quirk: use a function instead of a string in `StrLenField`

```
class Foo(Packet):
    name = "Foo"
    fields_desc = [
        VarLenQField("len", None, "data"),
        StrLenField("data", "", length_from=lambda pkt: pkt.len)
    ]
```

also wow there's a wrong example on the page that uses a string. I'll have that fixed

Comment: thanks, and thanks for imrpoving the scapy documentation.